# aws + serverless + webpack => cannot find module xxx in prod

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, webpack, serverless-framework, serverless-architecture

I want to create a package to deploy on AWS using **serverless** and **webpack**.

In `serverless.yml` I want to declare all the resources (mainly DynamoDb tables) and the functions. I want to use external `node.js` libraries.

The folder structure is:

```
|- serverless.yml
|- webpack.config.js
|- package.json
|- src 
  \ - file1.js
  | - file2.js
```

Extract from serverless.yml

```
functions:
  function1:
    handler: src/file1.f1
  function2:
    handler: src/file2.f2
```

Extract from webpack.congfig.js

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    file1: './src/file1.js',
    file2: './src/file2.js',
  },
  target: 'node',
  output: {
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
    path: path.join(__dirname, '.webpack'),
    filename: '[name].js',
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loaders: ['json-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

When doing a `serverless deploy` everything is ok, but when testing the lambda I get an error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Cannot find module '/var/task/src/file1'",
  "errorType": "Error",
  "stackTrace": [
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)",
    "Module.require (module.js:353:17)",
    "require (internal/module.js:12:17)"
  ]
}
```

**Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?**

**Given that I am a newbie with serverless, can you suggest me some "better practice" for the code and development organisation?** (serverless and nodejs are imposed, webpack and everything else is not)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend using the [serverless-webpack plugin](https://github.com/elastic-coders/serverless-webpack). It's hard to tell without seeing the entire `serverless.yml` file, but I would assume that serverless is trying to deploy the functions listed under `functions:`, which in your case are written in a syntax not understood by the Node.js 4.3 runtime on AWS lambda.

A good walk through on how to set up a project using the `serverless-webpack` plugin has been detailed by [Serverless Stack](http://serverless-stack.com/):

1. [Setup the Serverless Framework](http://serverless-stack.com/chapters/setup-the-serverless-framework.html)
2. [Add Support for ES6 JavaScript](http://serverless-stack.com/chapters/add-support-for-es6-javascript.html)

Comment: By reading the links things are getting more clear. I've solved my blocking situation by removing the `src/` of handler in `serverless.yml` file.

Answer (score 3):

### Check the node version

> node --version
>
> ### Run
>
> serverless plugin install --name serverless-webpack

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution to the error is to remove the `src/` from the handler of the function in `serverless.yml` file.

This approach has the side effect that when automatically creating tests with `serverless-mocha-plugin` the `src/` is no longer considered and it must be added manually in `const mod = require('../src/user.js');`.

There may be other side effects, *absence of evidence is not evidence of absence!* :)

So, **I'm still looking for a solution without side effects**.